# How to preprocess text for embedding?

Tags: neural-network, nlp

In the traditional "one-hot" representation of words as vectors you have a vector of the same dimension as the cardinality of your vocabulary. To reduce dimensionality usually stopwords are removed, as well as applying stemming, lemmatizing, etc. to normalize the features you want to perform some NLP task on.

I'm having trouble understanding whether/how to preprocess text to be embedded (e.g. word2vec). My goal is to use these word embeddings as features for a NN to classify texts into topic A, not topic A, and then perform event extraction on them on documents of topic A (using a second NN).

My first instinct is to preprocess removing stopwords, lemmatizing stemming, etc. But as I learn about NN a bit more I realize that applied to natural language, the CBOW and skip-gram models would in fact require the whole set of words to be present --to be able to predict a word from context one would need to know the actual context, not a reduced form of the context after normalizing... right?). The actual sequence of POS tags seems to be key for a human-feeling prediction of words.

I've found [some guidance online](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/word2vec-toolkit/TI-TQC-b53w) but I'm still curious to know what the community here thinks:

1. Are there any recent commonly accepted best practices regarding punctuation, stemming, lemmatizing, stopwords, numbers, lowercase etc?
2. If so, what are they? Is it better in general to process as little as possible, or more on the heavier side to normalize the text? Is there a trade-off?

My thoughts:

It is better to remove punctuation (but e.g. in Spanish don't remove the accents because the do convey contextual information), change written numbers to numeric, do not lowercase everything (useful for entity extraction), no stemming, no lemmatizing.

Does this sound right?

Answer (score 4):

I've been working on this problem myself for some time. I totally agree with the other answers, that it really depends on your problem and you must match your input to the output that you expect.
I found that for certain tasks like sentiment analysis it's OK to remove lot's of nuances by preprocessing, but e.g. for text generation, it is quite essential to keep everything.

I'm currently working on generating Latin text and therefore I need to keep quite a lot of structure in the data.

I found a very interesting paper doing some analysis on that topic, but it covers only a small area. However, it might give you some more hints:

On the Role of Text Preprocessing in Neural Network Architectures: An Evaluation Study on Text Categorization and Sentiment Analysis
by Jose Camacho-Collados and Mohammad Taher Pilehvar

https://arxiv.org/pdf/1707.01780.pdf

Here is a quote from their conclusion:

"Our evaluation highlights the importance of being consistent in the preprocessing strategy employed across training and evaluation data. In general a simple tokenized corpus works equally or better than more complex preprocessing techniques such as lemmatization or multiword grouping, except for a dataset corresponding to a specialized domain, like health, in which sole tokenization performs poorly. Addi- tionally, word embeddings trained on multiword- grouped corpora perform surprisingly well when applied to simple tokenized datasets."

Comment: I briefly reviewed the Collados paper, which is very nice. Are you aware of any text simplification, i.e. sentence simplication library in python or R using this or something similar ?

Answer (score 3):

So many questions. The answer to all of them is probably "depends". It needs to be considered the classes you are trying to predict and the kind of documents you have. It's not the same to try to predict authorship (then you definitely need to keep all kinds of punctuation and case so stylometry will work) than sentiment analysis (where you can get rid of almost everything but have to pay special attention to things like negations).

Answer (score 3):

I would say apply the same preprocessing to both ends. The surface forms are your link so you can't normalise in different ways. I do agree with the point *Joseph Valls* makes, but my impression is that most embeddings are trained in a generic rather than a specific manner. What I mean is that the Google News embeddings perform quite well on various different tasks and I don't think they had some fancy preprocessing. Getting enough data tends to be more important. All that being said -- it still depends :-)